# systemd attempts to mount davfs2 too early - before DHCP address received

Tags: debian, systemd, davfs2

I'm trying to get `davfs2` to mount a WebDAV folder automatically on debian stretch at boot.

It seems that `systemd` attempts to mount the folder with `mount.davfs` before the DHCP client has an IP address (which of course fails), even with the `_netdev` mount option in `/etc/fstab`. (Without `_netdev`, mounting also fails but so does the entire boot process and I'm dropped into a root shell during boot.)

What magic can I give `davfs` so that it only tries to mount after we've gotten an IP address with DHCP? (And why isn't this the default...)

As can be seen from the `journalctl` output below, `davfs2` attempts to mount before the DHCPACK and NFS mounts successfully *after* the DHCPACK. So NFS behaves, but `davfs2` fails.

```
> grep davfs /etc/fstab
https://example.com/remote.php/webdav/ /home/peter/pmorch davfs user,rw,auto,_netdev 0 0

> sudo journalctl --since 13:20:48 | grep -P 'davfs|pmorch|DHCP|ISO'
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden dhclient[669]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden sh[657]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden sh[657]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens18 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden dhclient[669]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens18 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/ISO-Dev...
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden systemd[1]: Mounting /home/peter/pmorch...
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/ISO...
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden mount.davfs[751]: davfs2 1.5.4
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden systemd[1]: home-peter-pmorch.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden systemd[1]: Failed to mount /home/peter/pmorch.
Jan 18 13:20:49 snowden systemd[1]: home-peter-pmorch.mount: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 18 13:20:50 snowden dhclient[669]: DHCPREQUEST of 172.22.216.172 on ens18 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jan 18 13:20:50 snowden sh[657]: DHCPREQUEST of 172.22.216.172 on ens18 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jan 18 13:20:50 snowden sh[657]: DHCPOFFER of 172.22.216.172 from 172.22.216.251
Jan 18 13:20:50 snowden dhclient[669]: DHCPOFFER of 172.22.216.172 from 172.22.216.251
Jan 18 13:20:50 snowden dhclient[669]: DHCPACK of 172.22.216.172 from 172.22.216.251
Jan 18 13:20:50 snowden sh[657]: DHCPACK of 172.22.216.172 from 172.22.216.251
Jan 18 13:20:52 snowden systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/ISO-Dev.
Jan 18 13:20:52 snowden systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/ISO.
```

Comment: I stumbled over your question trying to solve the same problem and found this link that has a very elegant solution based on systemd: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=322891

Comment: I'm sorry, @zero0cool there are many solutions in there and it wasn't really clear which of them worked. Could I ask you exactly what the elegant solution is?

Comment: Sure. I can't put this into an answer (not enough reputation).

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1835418#p1835418

2nd answer from the bottom worked for me after adjusting the values to my setup.
Don't forget the 'systemctl daemon-reload' after editing /etc/fstab

Answer (score 0):

As described in [systemd: start service at boot time after network is really up (for WoL purpose)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805354/systemd-start-service-at-boot-time-after-network-is-really-up-for-wol-purpose), for some incredibly weird reason that I won't pretend to understand, the systemd target `network-online` (and other reasonable-sounding targets) are reached *before* we get a DHCP IP address. (That just seems *wrong*).

My guess is that this is the reason why `fstab`s `_netdev` tries to mount it too early.

Instead, I've removed the line from `/etc/fstab` entirely and now done:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

And created `/etc/systemd/system/home-peter-pmorch.mount`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount pmorch WebDAV Service
After=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
Wants=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

[Mount]
What=https://example.com/remote.php/webdav/
Where=/home/peter/pmorch
Options=uid=peter,gid=peter,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=2775,grpid
Type=davfs
TimeoutSec=15

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now it gets mounted at boot time. And after a network problem I can no longer do `mount -a` but must

```
sudo systemctl start home-peter-pmorch.mount
```

But now at least it works.